# In Wso2 ESB 4.8.1, SFTP file movement is very slow

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are working using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. We are trying to move the around 250 files of size just 4 KB each. It is taking more than 3 to 4 hours for the transfer. Can you please help on this.

Comment: And if you tried to move them with winscp, how long will that take ?

Comment: It is taking around 3 to 4 minutes. Is there any tuning to be done in vfs ?

Comment: I do not have this problem : what are you doing in your mediation, what do you do after file process (move or delete), if move, where do you move the files ; could you share your proxy definition ?

Comment: Thanks. we are doing a move operation into a local folder on the same server were ESB is installed. By the way, we solved it. The issue was with the SFTP server. It was tuned and was shifted to the same region. Now it is taking less than a second to transfer one file.